# Screen Edge Pan Gesture + Table View Scrolling at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll, swipe

I have a UITableView which displays a bunch of users in a list. This can be loaded via a simple Push segue from a previous View Controller.
I'm facing a weird issue where if I try to use the ScreenEdgePanGesture to `Swipe to go back`, and stop while dragging, I can also move up and down and that causes the TableView to scroll. I uploaded an image below which shows the state I am describing. At that point, I can move left-right and perform the `Swipe to go back` gesture, but I can also move up-down and scroll the table.

I would like to disable the TableView scroll when the screen is dragged to be dismissed.

[image]

I've tried to add code to disable multiple gesture recognisers, but that seemed to have no effect.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return NO;
}
```

Is there any way in which I can disable this behaviour?
I would like to mention that I have observed the desired behaviour on other screens, where the TableView gets locked down as soon as the dragging gesture begins. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to discern any difference in the implementation of the classes or the arrangement in the Storyboard. By looking around at SO questions, I noticed that the correct and native behaviour is the one I desire. However, the screen I posted above behaves differently from what seems to be the norm. I cannot identify any peculiarities about it.

Extra information about the settings of the faulty TableView. Maybe someone can spot something wrong.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hifhb.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3OH2.jpg

I added an extra video to further display the problem. I hope this makes more sense: https://vid.me/Tp34

Many thanks!

Comment: I cannot replicate this in my app. Can you provide sample?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't provide a sample since this is a small component that is integrated in large application. However, if you're willing, I can give you the details so you can go and download it from iTunesConnect and can guide you through how to get to the screen I'm talking about.

Comment: But you still can try to replicate this issue in demo project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to find a solution for this. I'm not sure what was causing the behaviour, but in case any one is still struggling with this, this is what I did to disable the TableView from scrolling:

Added ScreenEdgePanRecognizer to my view:

```
self.panRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didPan)];
[self.panRecognizer setEdges:UIRectEdgeLeft];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.panRecognizer];
```

Then, I added a method which disables the scroll as soon as you start dragging, and re-enables is at soon as you're done with your gesture:

```
- (void)didPan {
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    if ([self.panRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```

This now disables the scroll mid-gesture, but then restores it when you're done dragging.